# Add update services on theme activation

Tags: activation

I want add [update services](http://codex.wordpress.org/Update_Services) when I activate my theme, how to do this ?
with an hook like enable_update_services_configuration ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why on earth would you want to spam update services about activating a Theme?

Comment: Just need to automatically add some update services in addition to the basic ones on theme activation

Comment: If this is a publicly distributed Theme, I would **strongly recommend against** putting this sort of thing in the Theme. Defining update services to be pinged is the sort of functionality that should be left to Plugins.

Comment: Don't worry this is for personal use only. But thanks that's sounds like a great idea, i'll try doing it through the plugins rather than the theme.

Answer (score 2):

Themes [don't currently have activation/deactivation/installation/uninstallation hooks](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14955).

Your best bet is to "fake" it somehow, perhaps with a function that only executes one time, based on a switch that gets toggled when the function executes. e.g.:

```
<?php
function wpse45817_theme_activation() {
    // globalize our switch
    global $wpse45817_theme_activation_switch;
    // Check to see if the switch is set
    if ( isset( $wpse45817_theme_activation_switch ) ) {
        return;
    } else {
        // EXECUTE YOUR THEME-ACTIVATION CODE HERE
        //
        //
        // Toggle Theme activation switch
        $wpse45817_theme_activation_switch = true;
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse45817_theme_activation' );
?>
```